# Maven POM dependencies without a version?

Tags: java, maven

If you don't specify a version in your POM dependencies, what version of the jar gets picked up as a dependency to be used in a project?

I work on a project with many dozens of developers, repositories and POM files and explicit versions are sometimes indicated. In the case that they're not, however, do the versions of the dependency in the PARENT POM get picked up?

Comment: Is there a "dependencyManagement" section where the version is defined?

Comment: More than half of the tags that you chose were irrelevant to your question.  Please only use relevant tags.